# Getting POST parameters in Node.js, using Express.js

Tags: node.js, http, post, express

I'm trying to get some POST parameters following a request using Express, but I cannot get the data. Here's my `app.configure`:

```
app.configure(function() {
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');

    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());

    app.use(gzippo.staticGzip(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use(gzippo.compress());
});
```

After a POST HTTP request, I try to ouptut it in the console:

```
console.log(req.body);
```

The object is always empty.

Any idea on what I forgot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I needed to do it, was to add the body parser and app.post lines from this code:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
    .use(express.favicon())
    .use(express.bodyParser())
    .use(express.cookieParser(COOKIE_P))
    .use(express.session());

app.post('/',function(req,res){
    res.writeHead(200,{"content-type":"text/html;charset=UTF8;"});
    res.end("POST");
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

My fail was try to get the values from app.get instead of app.post.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use **req.body** to retrieve body parameters. You must use a form in your HTML code too.

Example:

```
<form action="myaction" method="post">
  <input name="address" id="address" type="text" />
  <button type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

...

In your form:

```
var address = req.body.address; //get address value
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to swap the following lines:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
```